# How can I access the mysql command line tool when using XAMPP in OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I've got a vanilla install of XAMPP in OS X. How can I access the mysql command line tool? I've tried typing "mysql" at the command line, and it spits back "-bash: mysql: command not found".

Answer (score 47, accepted):

XAMPP is installed in Mac OS X in the following directory:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/
```

You can look what's inside that directory and run **mysql** command line tool providing the full path to it:

```
$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

If you need, you can modify your **PATH** environment variable to include XAMPP binaries and you won't need to specify the whole path all the time.

Answer (score 20):

1. Open your .profile file in Mac. This can be done by entering the terminal and typing

   ```
   pico ~/.profile
   ```
2. Add the following line to your ./profile file. Replace the path where you installed Xampp, however by default this is the route and should work:

   ```
   export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Open a new terminal window (Recommendation is to quit all terminal windows and then reopen) and type:

   ```
   mysql
   ```

That is all, isn't easy!!

Comment: After these steps you need logout or run 'source ~/.profile' command to reload your .profile file.

Comment: Together with Capy's comment - great answer!

Comment: I've tried all of the recommendation here, but still I got a "command not found: mysql"

Answer (score 5):

Open terminal and Follow this bellow step to add mysql to your mac environmental variable

step 1:

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

step 2:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH
```

save it by control+x and then y and hit return. That's it!! now close the terminal and reopen

```
mysql --version
```

this will tell you which MySQL version you are using with xampp

Comment: this should be added ~/.profile rather than ~/.bash_profile as it is an enviromental variable and has nowt to do with bash.  https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc

Answer (score 4):

Before using the `mysql` command, make sure that you start up the server first by running

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Then you will be able to use the commands `mysqladmin` and `mysql`.

To shut it down, run

```
$ mysql.server stop
```

and to restart just use

```
$ mysql.server restart
```

Very intuitive.

Comment: @tq, don't type the `$` -- that's a stand-in for the bash prompt

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment on the accepted answer by Pablo Santa Cruz - Here's some additional info. If you're going to modify your PATH environment variable to include XAMPP binaries, make sure you add

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

and not

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
```

to the /etc/paths file. To do this run the command

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

then add the path to the file. Save using Ctrl+O and exit using Ctrl+X. Quit terminal and open again.