# How do I access the mysql commandline tool with XAMPP VM on mac?

Tags: mysql, xampp-vm

I am just beginning to learn about databases and I installed XAMPP on my macBook for that purpose. I would like to use the 'mysql' commandline tool but my installation of XAMPP is ran as a separate VM which means that I don't have a path from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql available. The closest thing I have been able to find is the path to this root directory :

/Users/kafka/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root

which contains a bin folder leading to a mysql file.

/Users/kafka/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/bin/mysql

Could I use that path to run the commandline tool or am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate of this i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354046/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-tool-when-using-xampp-in-os-x

Comment: you should look for the xamp control panel. You should find a shell button (at least this is how it looks on windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354046/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-tool-when-using-xampp-in-os-x I looked at this and it seemed to be relating to a non-VM install of XAMPP which includes a path my installation doesn't have.

Comment: There is an 'open terminal' button in the control panel which opens a terminal window with the prompt : root@debian:~#, however when I issue an 'ls' command I get no ouput and pwd gives only /root. So I don't see how this window relates to the root folder in my path /Users/kafka/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root (which isn't empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the 'Open Terminal' Button inside your XAMPP App you can simply call mysql with `mysql -u root`.